# VueJS HTML element type based on condition

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

in Vue JS, I can do

`<h1 v-if="someCondition">MY TITLE</h1>`

Is there a way to base the element type on some condition?

For example, based on `someCondition` I want my title to be `<h1>` or `<h2>`.

I suppose I could use

```
<template v-if="someCondition === 0">
  <h1>MY TITLE</h1>
</template>

<template v-if="someCondition === 1">
  <h2>MY TITLE</h2>
</template>
```

But is there a more straightforward way of writing this?

Comment: Are you looking for component dynamic v-bind:is?  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html or a good read https://alligator.io/vuejs/dynamic-components/

Comment: Try this.

    <component :is="someCondition===0?'h1':'h2'" label="Settings">MY TITLE</component>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<component :is="'h'+someCondition">MY TITLE</component>
```

your "someCondition" can be defined as props or data property and it can have a value from 1 to 6, in case you are going to use only "H tags"

Answer (score 4):

If there is only 2 variations your best bet is to stick with `v-if` and `v-else`.

If there are more possible variations a dynamic component is the way to go (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html)

```
<component :is="dynamicComponent">Foo</component>

...

computed: {
  dynamicComponent() {
    return 'h'+this.i
  }
}
```

Which will in turn render into `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h{i}>`.
This is more useful though when switching between actual components, not the HTML `h` tags.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-z40u7

Answer (score 2):

This is where `render` functions are useful.  Whenever your template needs more advanced logic, render functions offer the use of Javascript with all of its logic flow capacity to generate the template, rather than HTML tags.  You can read more about [Vue's render functions here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html).

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/mh2qa7y1/) to demonstrate this example:

```
data() {
  return {
    someCondition: 1
  }
},
render(h){
  let tagType;
  if (this.someCondition === 0) {
    tagType = 'h1';
  } else if(this.someCondition === 1) {
    tagType = 'h2';
  }
  return h(tagType, null, 'MY TITLE');
}
```